# Where is .dmp files located in a computer

Tags: windows, windows-8

Where is the .dmp files located in windows 8 Pro ? If anyone knows please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\Windows\Minidump\

When you get a crash or bluescreen, you can see the name of the .dmp for that crash on next boot up.

you can analyze them online [here](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze).